# Cache channel service default port in case of second

Tags: web8.5, cache-channel-service

I have installed 2 instances of cache channel micro servive for Staging and Live environment. I have left with default port. How can I find, which port my second instance is using? Also how can I register it as a capability with discovery service?

Comment: http://elenaserghie.blogspot.in/2013/10/under-magnifying-glass-cache-channel.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two instances of the service listen on the same port. One will fail.

One option is to configure the services to run on separate ports like this: 
[Is it possible to specify your own port number for the cache microservice](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/16469/129)

You could also consider running the instances on separate servers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As suggested in your question, I am able to setup the port. I am wondering why server.port parameter suggested in SDL docs is not working. Is there anything missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at the readme.md file available with the Cache channel service installation for the default port

```
in both cases (windows and linux) the service will be reachable on port:`1099`.
```

Comment: As 1099 is already in use by staging cache channel service, I am wondering how can live also use that?